# Flutter DropdownButtonFormField selected background color

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a DropdownButtonFormField that have few option to select. After select the option and open back the selection list, how to changes the background color of the previous selected option? To indicate that the previous selected option

[image]
[image]

```
String _selectedPicGroup;

static const _picGroup = [
    'Group A',
    'Group B',
    'Group C',
    'Group D',
  ];

SizedBox(
        height: 78,
        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: InputBorder.none,
            filled: true,
            fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
          ),
          hint: Text('Please select group'),
          isExpanded: true,
          isDense: true,
          value: _selectedPicGroup,
          items: _picGroup.map((item) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: item,
                        child: Text(item),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
          validator: (value) =>
                        value?.isEmpty ?? true ? 'Cannot Empty' : null,
          onChanged: (selectedItem) => setState(
                      () {
                        _selectedPicGroup = selectedItem;
                      },
                    ),
        ),
      );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `selectedItemBuilder` and in `items:` check `if (item == _selectedPicGroup)` then return customize `DropdownMenuItem`

```
selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
      return _picGroup.map<Widget>((String item) {
        print("$item");
        return DropdownMenuItem(value: item, child: Text(item));
      }).toList();
    },
items: _picGroup.map((item) {
  if (item == _selectedPicGroup) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: item,
      child: Container(
          height: 48.0,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              item,
            ),
          )),
    );
  } else {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      value: item,
      child: Text(item),
    );
  }
}).toList(),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _selectedPicGroup;

  static const _picGroup = [
    'Group A',
    'Group B',
    'Group C',
    'Group D',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 78,
              child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey[300],
                ),
                hint: Text('Please select group'),
                isExpanded: true,
                isDense: true,
                value: _selectedPicGroup,
                selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return _picGroup.map<Widget>((String item) {
                    print("$item");
                    return DropdownMenuItem(value: item, child: Text(item));
                  }).toList();
                },
                items: _picGroup.map((item) {
                  if (item == _selectedPicGroup) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: item,
                      child: Container(
                          height: 48.0,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          child: Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Text(
                              item,
                            ),
                          )),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: item,
                      child: Text(item),
                    );
                  }
                }).toList(),
                validator: (value) =>
                    value?.isEmpty ?? true ? 'Cannot Empty' : null,
                onChanged: (selectedItem) => setState(
                  () {
                    _selectedPicGroup = selectedItem;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```